# Site review: how to vote if I find a different Blender.SE answer?

Tags: discussion, support

During the review, I was asked to give my opinion about [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23349/importing-time-dependent-mesh).

Doing a Google search, I found [a different question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/607/generate-curve-from-equation) on third place, which I'd say provides at least an alternative to what the OP wants to do.

How to vote in this case?

The *site* does a great job, but the particular question doesn't. I voted for "Needs improvement", mainly because it

> has an answer that is no better than what can be found elsewhere

Is my vote correct or should I have voted differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voting is a democratic process, whether it's a general election or a review queue here on SE, or anything in between. The idea is to make your voice heard. A vote isn't wrong if it reflects your view. Whether others agree with your view or not, is beside the point.
If "Needs improvement" is how you feel, then your vote is correct. If others said "Satisfactory" or "Excellent", your view is still just as valid.

For the question you link to, I also voted "Needs improvement", but for other reasons. I must have done other searches than you, because I had a hard time getting the question to show up on Google. But I feel that that proves my point; different people see things differently.

Answer (score 1):

Your vote doesn't need to be correct, just *honest*.